# Implementing RSA in C++

Tags: c++

I am implementing RSA algorithm in C++ and here's my design(code structure).

`keygen.h`

```
namespace rsa{
    class keygen{
        public:
        //Constructor
        keygen(size);
        //Generate keys
        void generate();
        //Getters
        char* gete(){ return xyz; }
        .. 
        ..
        ..

        private:
        //initializes bignums
        void initall();
        //Private Member variables goes here
   }
}
```

`prime.h`

```
namespace rsa{
    //First 100 primes
    unsigned int primes[]={2,3,5,7,11.....541};

    //MillarRabin Primality
    bool isPrime(mpz_t, unsigned short);
    //Get Random Prime
    void getPrime(mpz_t, mpz_t)
}
```

`endec.h`

```
namespace rsa{
    //Encryption
    const char* encryption(const char* text, const char* n, const char* e);
    //Decryption
    const char* decryption(const char* cipher, const char* n, const char* d);
}
```

**Is this a good design? How can I make it better?** I want to improve the structure or the overall design, that's why dint post any code. Things like naming standards, using classes wherever applicable, standard function signature and similar is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think you did not provide enough information - just a few lines of code. It's hard to say something interesting about this besides trivial things like "it is better to use `Keygen` instead of `keygen` for a class name".

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not how RSA public key encryption works. You need to do more research on it but I do not expect to see you passing a password to the `encrypt()` `decrypt()` functions. And what is with passing char* pointers around use std::string to represent a password or create a `Key` type to represent a key etc.

Comment: @Michael- I want to improve the design, that's why dint post any code. Added more details in question.

Comment: @LokiAstari- Can you please tell me why you think so? Why passing passwords(keys here) as arguments is a bad idea? I can use strings, will change that.

Comment: Because public key encryption does not involve passwords. You have a public and private key. Encryption involves using your private key and the receivers public key. While decryption uses your public key and the recievers private key. If it is just you then you just use your key. But the key is not a password it is a cryptographically complex key object. See http://code.google.com/p/rsa/source/browse/rsa/trunk/#trunk%2Fsource

Comment: @LokiAstari- I know that and I never mentioned password anywhere. N and E are required for encryption, and N and D are required for decryption, that's what I'm passing as arguments.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is primarily a design review and not a code review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple of short comments as a starting point.

First of all, you don't need separate encrypt and decrypt functions -- the algorithm is identical for both. You just pass different parameters for them.

Second, I wouldn't use `char const *` for the input or output of the encrypt/decrypt function. It might be barely allowable for the plaintext (since you *could* restrict that to not contain zero bytes) but is definitely not acceptable as the encrypted data (since you can't stop it from containing zero bytes). Since, however, the same function can do either encryption or decryption, you don't want to use `char const *` for input *or* output. Personally, I'd probably have it take iterators for the input and output, so you can work with `string`, `vector<char>`, `vector<wchar_t>`, etc.

Finally, I don't think I'd put implementation details like the first 100 primes directly in the `rsa` namespace -- I'd have `rsa` contain a `detail` namespace to contain details like that. I'm not sure I'd have `keygen` either -- I think I'd make `key` a class, probably with the default ctor deleted, and a static member function to create a key, and overloading `operator>>` and `operator<<` to serialize keys in a standard format (e.g., X.509, PKCS #8). About all that would be visible to the outside world would be `key` and `crypt` (or whatever you decide to call the combined encrypt/decrypt funct(ion|or).

Edit: the `key` class and signatures would be something like this:

```
class key { 
    key() = delete; // `=delete;` is C++11 only; without that just declare private
public:
    static key create_key();
};
```

Comment: That was the type of answer I was looking for, thank you Sir. But why passing iterators is better than passing strings directly? and can you please give little more detail about using static member function(signature) and overloading operators?

Comment: Iterators let you change outside data types more easily, and they're easier to string together with other algorithms, data structures, etc. See edited answer about function signatures.

Comment: And how is the user supposed to get those keys(n,e and d)? Using operators `>>` and `<<`?

Comment: @vidit: Yes, you'd generate a new key with `key::generate_key()`, and use `operator<<` to write it to a stream and `operator>>` to read it from a stream. I haven't bothered to show those, but they follow pretty much the usual pattern: `std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, key const &);` and `std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, key &);`

Comment: Thanks again Sir. One last question, is this the right question for CodeReview?

Comment: @vidit: Yes, I'd say it's a reasonable question here. Perhaps others will weigh in with opinions on that, though any extended discussion of it should probably go to [meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/).